# How to sign miners rewards on a blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Don't kill me if I'm about to ask something stupid. But I'm very noobish in this whole crypto world, and I'm terribly fascinated about its technology.

So just for education purposes I've decided to build my own blockchain following more or less the bitcoin principles (ECC keypair generation using the *secpbk1* curve, *SHA256* as hashing algo, dynamic diff based on the timestamp of the previous block, p2p connectivity etc..). But I've came to a point where I'm pretty confused about the blockchain's wallet itself.

For what I've learned so far, each transaction **has** to be signed by a wallet. So my transactions has basically three fields: *input*, *outputs* and *id*. Since the user's wallet signs the *outputs* field of the transaction, this can't be changed anymore without being signed again by the same private key that belongs to the public key contained in the *input* field, how can I reward the miners?

If I got it right, the miner creates a transaction signed somehow by the chain using the fee in the *outputs* field, or by asking the chain itself to generate and sign a special *reward* transaction for that miner.

The guide that I was following was using the second approach, and was generating a blockchain wallet each time the program was executed on a client. This approach left me perplexed:

wouldn't a client generate a new wallet for "his" blockchain each time it goes back online? If so, wouldn't this create a mess on the transactions signed on the chain? Since each miner (therefore peer) signing its own reward would use a different blockchain wallet than the other peers? Wouldn't this lead to any problems?

The first one that I might think of, is that if we generate a new blockchain wallet that signs rewards for miners, each peer would create a different wallet, so wouldn't this lead to many "ghosts" wallets in the chain, that spits out rewards tokens from nowhere? Is this supposed to happen?

For what I think is definitively more straightforward to use the fee amount to reward the miner, but this doesn't solve my doubts at all. Since the outputs of the transactions are signed upon creation, how could the peer initiating the transaction know upfront the possible miner who finds the block? And if he can't know it, how could possibly the miner "extract" its reward without tampering the transaction itself? Of course it could create a new transaction, and add that to the block. But who would sign that transaction? From where those reward tokens come?

And if the answer is not to generate a new wallet each time, where could you possibly store that very first private key of the chain's wallet where no one can see it, but still be able to use it, without having to put a server in the middle?

Which in my opinion breaks the whole decentralized concept and would add a single point of failure.

I've also implemented a transactions pool, that automatically filters out invalid (tampered) transactions, whenever a miner requests a sub set of them to stamp in a block. But does this mean that the miner for that only exception can tamper the transaction since it'll be "forged" in the block? So who gives a *** if it was tampered once it got in the chain? MEEEEEH that doesn't sound nice at all.

I'm terribly confused, and I'm dreaming key pairs at night. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wouldn't a client generate a new wallet for "his" blockchain each time it goes back online? If so, wouldn't this create a mess on the transactions signed on the chain? Since each miner (therefore peer) signing its own reward would use a different blockchain wallet than the other peers? Wouldn't this lead to any problems?

You don't say what problems you think this will lead to. I can't think of any.

> For what I think is definitively more straightforward to use the fee amount to reward the miner, but this doesn't solve my doubts at all. Since the outputs of the transactions are signed upon creation, how could the peer initiating the transaction know upfront the possible miner who finds the block? And if he can't know it, how could possibly the miner "extract" its reward without tampering the transaction itself?

The simplest solution to this is for the transaction itself to just contain its inputs and outputs. The fee is the difference between the total inputs and the total outputs.

The miner just includes the transaction in the block of transactions they mine. They also add one additional transaction into the block, sending themselves the reward. Obviously, they know their own destination address. Every participant who receives the newly-mined block checks to make sure this transaction is valid (just as they check every other one) and doesn't claim a larger reward than is allowed.

> And if the answer is not to generate a new wallet each time, where could you possibly store that very first private key of the chain's wallet where no one can see it, but still be able to use it, without having to put a server in the middle?

Typically in a file on the local disk. The private key isn't really needed anyway -- you only need it to *send*. You don't need it to mine or report. So it can be prompted for or decrypted only when actually needed.

> Of course it could create a new transaction, and add that to the block. But who would sign that transaction? From where those reward tokens come?

The usual rule is that the reward transaction has no inputs, one output, and no signature. The tokens come from the pool of unclaimed miner reward tokens which can be finite or infinite depending on the blockchain's design. (For bitcoin, this pool is finite.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the first problem I see in creating a new wallet that signs the miner reward each time, is that there's no single blockchain's wallet, but it's kinda non existent. Is this behaviour allowed? A "ghost" wallet that spits token from nowhere?

Comment: I've updated the question trying to answer you on the parts you've cited, since a comment would be too long

Comment: @Caius It's not a ghost wallet that spits tokens from nowhere, it's the rule that allows tokens to be created in the first place. The miner is permitted to attach a "reward" transaction with one output and no inputs.

Comment: ok, now it's a bit more clear. So basically it can create a new transaction with no inputs and just an output for itself? But how can be no inputs? if the signature is in the input field? Isn't that transaction signed too? With which wallet key?

Comment: @Caius There's no reason to sign it and very good reasons not to. You don't want mining equipment to have to have private keys.

Comment: With the last edit to your question, I've got it right. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh, one correction. Bitcoin does allow the reward transaction to have multiple outputs. That makes it more convenient for cases where miners are splitting rewards.

Comment: thank you again for your time, you can't imagine how happy I am, now that it "clicked" <3

Comment: Glad to help. That's an awesome feeling.